# close all opened resources once the window is closed on php

Tags: javascript, php

i have an object that use some resources like

```
class UseResources {

    protected $proc_open;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->proc_open = proc_open( ... );
    }

    public function cleanup()
    {
        proc_close($this->proc_open);
    } 
};
```

i tried to send an ajax request on `.unload` event, but its not what am looking for.

i want to be able to call the cleanup method once the user close the window or the browser, or once the connection is lost?

Answer (score 1):

The `unload` event fires when the window closes, but also when user refreshes the page or navigates to a new page (even if new page is within your site). I recommend against using `unload` in this case. (`unload` is better used for things like prompting user to save or lose changes before leaving a form, for example.)

Also, if you implement a javascript solution you either want to (1) require javascript to use the site (and show `<noscript></noscript>` element to folks with JS disabled), or (2) code such that you are not relying solely on your window close / cleanup detection routine to release resources.

The strategy I typically implement to do stuff like this is to use a ping process. Basically: the client sends regular pings to the server which resets the connection's/session's `idle` counter to `0` when it receives a ping. The pings occur every minute or so depending on need. A long-running looping thread (a `Session` manager, if you will) then checks for any clients that have idled beyond the `idle threshhold` (say 3 minutes, but up to you), and if exceeded releases the resources tied to that connection/session. Then every page (where appropriate) in your site adds this ping code so that the client starts pinging for as long as the page is open in the browser.

**Benefits**

- keeps track of how long user is viewing your site (useful for metrics, especially when coupled with a metric for tracking number of requests)
- closes all connection-related resources when browser is closed, and also when user navigates away from your site
- if user navigates to different page [that has ping code] on your site their connection resources will not be cleared because the `idle` counter will reset on the next page

**Drawbacks**

- requires javascript (`setTimeout` or `setInterval` and `XMLHttpRequest`, for example)
- unless you also have something like an "authentication timeout" on the server, the client could potentially keep your server (and resources) connected for a long time if user walks away from an open web browser for a while (you could get around this by using alternate ping triggers such as mouse movement, setting focus to form fields, clicking, scrolling, etc.)

Rough example code for client page:

```js
function pingServer() {
  var req;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
      alert("Idle timer reset on server");
    }
  }
  var url = 'ping.php'; // call php code that will reset idle timer for this client
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.send();
}
var pingFrequencyMs = 5 * 1000; // ping every 5 secs
setInterval(pingServer, pingFrequencyMs);
```

```html
<noscript>Sorry, JavaScript is required for this website.</noscript>
```

And here is a really rough example of process you could use on server side, but until you provide more details I can only speculate about what kind of web app you are working with:

**Server Ping routine (pseudocode, could be PHP, ASP, JSP, etc.)**

1. get client connection `unique ID` (or Session ID, or whatever)
2. get current value for client `idle` timer, else default to `0` (could get this from memory cache, database, file on disk; your choice)
3. get system value for `max idle` (timeout)
4. compare client `idle` to `max idle`
5. if client `idle` exceeds `max idle` then end the session (whatever that means; close connection/session-specific resources, etc. -- in your case it means call the `cleanup` routine, but make sure it has the correct object context), else reset `idle` to `0`